# Extraction of arthropod embedded in animal tissue

Tags: lab-techniques, histology

I'd like to extract an ectoparasite from a biopsy of animal skin for subsequent identification. The mite is small, about 100 um, and embedded in a column of tissue. It's too small to manually excise under magnification. Currently preserved in 70% ethanol.

Ideally I would isolate it by loosening or dissolving the surrounding tissue without destroying its features. I'd like to conduct a visual inspection prior to sequencing for species identification. Specific suggestions and techniques welcome.

See photo:

[image: http://s32.postimg.org/4nm6krc79/specimen_2c.jpg]